# Since update to Mojave SD card disappears after sleep

Tags: sleep-wake, mojave, sd-card

Since an update to Mojave, the **SD card which I use permanently in my MBP 
always gets unmounted after longer sleep and importantly, it does only remount after restart.**

I know this question has been posted several times. However, the only solution I found which is supposed to solve this problem automatically (the tool "Mountain") is

A) not doing the job

B) crashes the mac sometimes I guess after hitting the "reactivate USB drives command

Anyone has a solution for that?

here some system.log details during sleep:

```
Oct  3 00:13:43 XXX-MacBook-Pro kcm[5005]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug

Oct  3 00:15:23 XXX-MacBook-Pro kcm[5011]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug

Oct  3 00:18:53 XXX-MacBook-Pro kcm[5070]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug

Oct  3 00:18:53XXX-MacBook-Pro syslogd[63]: ASL Sender Statistics

Oct  3 00:20:07XXX-MBP kcm[5085]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug

Oct  3 01:20:44 XXX-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.privax.osx.provpn.update): Service only ran for 601 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10199 seconds.

Oct  3 01:20:44 XXX-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.sandboxd[124]): Service exited due to SIGALRM | sent by kernel_task[0]

Oct  3 01:20:44 XXX-MBP syslogd[63]: ASL Sender Statistics

Oct  3 01:20:53 XXX-MBP kcm[5093]: DEPRECATED USE in libdispatch client: Setting timer interval to 0 requests a 1ns timer, did you mean FOREVER (a one-shot timer)?; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug

Oct  3 01:21:12 XXX-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.getdropbox.dropbox.garcon.XXX[726]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by Dropbox[545]

Oct  3 01:21:16 XXX-MBP com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.getdropbox.dropbox.2252[545]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by Dropbox[5117]
```

What I also get is the following ReportCrash message:

```
com.apple.message.domain: com.apple.crashreporter.writereport.crash
com.apple.message.signature: sshfs
com.apple.message.signature2: UNBUNDLED ||| ??? (???)
com.apple.message.signature3: UNKNOWN
com.apple.message.result: NO
com.apple.message.summarize: YES
SenderMachUUID: XXX
```

Comment: did you look at the console log during the sleep hours to see what is going on.

Comment: Hm yeah, can you tell what would be relevant to look at? I guess the most important part is happening in the time frame posted in the edited question, as my dropbox account is linked to the SD card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So its a problem with disk sleep. Actually the one have to disable it manually. In Terminal type: `sudo pmset -g` and than `sudo pmset -a disksleep 1410065408`.

Comment: It is however, sad that we need this workaround